# Printing SSRS Report from Webforms app C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, webforms

I'm trying to print an SSRS report from a webforms app written in C#. The report is loaded into a reportviewer and here is my code so far:

```
    protected void printAll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //loads report into reportviewer
        showReport("/SHOW_ALL");

        string mimeType;
        string encoding;
        string extension;
        string[] streams;
        Warning[] warnings;
        byte[] pdfBytes = ReportViewer.ServerReport.Render("IMAGE", string.Empty, out mimeType,
            out encoding, out extension, out streams, out warnings);

        string outputPath = "C://Temp/";
        string outputFile = Path.GetFileName(ReportViewer.ServerReport.ReportPath) + "_" + client.FullName + ".tiff";
        string fullOutput = outputPath + outputFile;

        if (File.Exists(fullOutput))
        {
            File.Delete(fullOutput);
        }
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullOutput, FileMode.Create))
        { 
            fs.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
            fs.Close();
        }


    }
```

I'm just trying to write the image to an iFrame and print it out. I've tried as a PDF but IE doesn't render anything (no built in pdf viewer) and if I use the .tiff option then there's no way to print anything but the first page. I've trawled through many articles related to winforms or various other technologies, none so far have helped. Something cross browser would be good, but at the moment I'm just looking for something that will work preferably with IE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I have tried with my previous project. Hope this help.

```
private void Export(ServerReport report)
    {
        Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.Warning[] webWarning = null;

        m_streams = new List<Stream>();

        NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

        string extension = null;
        string encoding = null;
        string mimeType = null;
        string type = "HTML4.0";

        Stream stream = report.Render(type, null, nvc, out mimeType, out extension);
        StreamReader f = new StreamReader(stream);
        string strHtml = f.ReadToEnd();

        int startStyle = strHtml.IndexOf("<style", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        int closeStyle = strHtml.IndexOf("</style>", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
        string style = strHtml.Substring(startStyle, closeStyle - startStyle) + "</style>";

        string body = strHtml.Substring(strHtml.IndexOf("<body", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
        body = body.Replace("</html>", "");
        body = body.Replace("<body", "<div");
        body = body.Replace("</body>", "</div>");

        string script = @"
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function print_me(idx) {
                var browser = navigator.userAgent;
                if (browser.indexOf('MSIE') >= 0) {
                    document.execCommand('print', false, null);
                }
                else {
                    window.print();
                }

            }

            $(function () {
                print_me();
            });
        </script>";

        expandPrintHtml.InnerHtml = style + body + script;           

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my scenario `expandPrintHtml` is an iFrame,  when run, this code just seems to hang and doesn't update the innerHtml at all. What kind of element were you using?

Comment: You can use <div runat="server" id="expandPrintHtml"></div>